# I want to build my own webhook dispatch server using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webhooks

I am trying to build a webhook server using node js. If any user sets their server URL as a hook using API provided by me, then my webhook server should respond to that user server.

I got this idea from the Facebook Messenger Chatbot application which uses the same approach.

**Server 1 - My Server**

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

/* Set Middleware to Express App */
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.post("/handle-webhooks", (req, res) => {
    const body = {"id": "1", "message": "hello"};
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
    }
    const clientWebhookUrl = "http://localhost:8093/webhook2" // This will be different for each client
    axios.post(clientWebhookUrl, body, {headers})
    return res.sendStatus(200);
})

app.post("/set-webhook", (req,res) => {
    const clientWebhookUrl = req.url;
    // This URL will be saved to database
    return res.sendStatus(200)
}

/* Listen Server */
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening on port ${PORT}.`);
})
```

**Server 2 - My Client 1 Server**

Using postman, the Client will make a post request to http://localhost:3000/set-webhook and set the webhook2 endpoint of his web server as a webhook URL to receive a response from my server.

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
const PORT = 8093;

/* Set Middleware to Express App */
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.post("/webhook2", (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body; // receives {"id": "1", "message": "hello"}
    return res.status(200).send(body);
})

/* Listen Server */
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening on port ${PORT}.`);
})
```

Is the above approach is correct for doing this task? or do I need to add more complex code for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting it. Server1 calls Server2 with `axios.post(clientWebhookUrl)`. And then? What else? It just replies `status:200` to your client? Server2 does reply to Server1 with `res.status(200).send(body)` but Server1 does nothing with it. Also, why two servers in the first place?

Comment: @JeremyThille Actually, I want to build service as other API service provider does, they give an endpoint (eg. https://demo-api.com/set-webhook) to the end-user so that he can connect his own server and receives a response from my server. So is it the correct approach for doing this task? Please help